# Wordpress Tag issue on tag archive page

Tags: wordpress, tags

From category.php Page I click on tag and it goes to tag.php page.

The following code returns the tag on archive/tag page.

But i adds a word "Tag:" before it.

Tag: tagname

How can I remove that "Tag:" and show only tag name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', function ($title) {

    if( is_tag() ) {

        $title = single_tag_title( '', false );

    }

    return $title;

});
```

You should paste it in your theme functions.php file.

Cheers!